# any way to have a 2 buttons beside each others that fills the width without having multiple xml files?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know if this is possible to have to buttons beside each others which fills the with in any screen size but without designing multiple xml layouts.
Is it possible?
I've found this information and I tried that, but not working for my purpose: [Android: Align LinearLayout center for all screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150780/android-align-linearlayout-center-for-all-screen-sizes)

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btnPersonalInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#FFC40D"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/person"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/personal_info"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btnLawyerInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#EE1111"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/lawyer"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/lawyer_info"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSharesInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#2976DE"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/shares"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/buy_sell"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFinancialInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#902293"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/wallet"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/financial_info"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNews"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#0D9A0E"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/news"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/news"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMessages"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#CA5A35"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/messages"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/messages"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSync"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/pink"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/sync"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/update"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#AF274D"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/quit"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/exit"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

in my 2 first buttons I set android:layout_weight="1" but nothing happs.

Comment: Ask on StackOverflow How-To : Provide details. Share your research.

Comment: Need clearer information. There should be no problem to implement what you ask currently in 1 layout, using `LinearLayout` and its `android:layout_weight` property.

Comment: @gahfy More details provided. thanks for your reminding.

Comment: @AndrewT. Derails provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you set the button's weight to a number, either it's width or height should be at 0dp

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

this button will only stretch up and down because it's height is 0dp

Comment: Whats the meaning of height="0dp" and what if it's not specified?

Comment: 0dp means 0 density-independent pixels, basically it means that your view will have zero pixels (on either height or width, whatever you choose). If I'm not wrong weight will affect either width or height (the one that has 0dp). I always do it this way and never had a problem, I could be wrong so if you can try it and tell me, if it doesnt work maybe i can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_weight` property, like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ... />
```

Comment: Please see:1.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html  2.http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html  3.http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html